# how to connect a sqlite DB in unity 3d 5?(no plugins)

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Hello i'm working on an android game project in unity3d 5 (language c#)that needs to save some data to sqlite database.
 the game doesn't have a lot of data to store it has only 1 table .there are some plugins for unity that connect to sqlite but i don't want to use them .
so how can i store my data on sqlite file in unity ?

Comment: I think this link can help you : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html

Answer (score 12):

You can find your answer [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html)

> 1. Create new folder under Assets Folder Rename it **Plugins** .
> 2. Copy **sqlite3.def** and **sqlite3.dll** into **Assets/Plugins** in your unity project .You can download these files here
>      http://www.sqlite.org/download.html for windows (Precompiled Binaries
>      for Windows)
> 3. Download SQLite Browser http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ or
>      http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/ download SQLite Administrator tool
> 4. Create Database in **Assets folder** in your unity project using SQLite Browser.
> 5. Copy **System.Data.dll** and **Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll** from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity \Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0* and paste them in your Assets/Plugins* folder in your unity project.
> 6. Add these namespaces **using Mono.Data.Sqlite; using System.Data; using System;**
> 7. string conn= "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/PickAndPlaceDatabase.s3db";
>
> Replace PickAndPlaceDatabase.s3db with your database name
>
> ```
> void Start () {
>     string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/PickAndPlaceDatabase.s3db"; //Path to database.
>     IDbConnection dbconn;
>     dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
>     dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
>     IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
>     string sqlQuery = "SELECT value,name, randomSequence " + "FROM PlaceSequence";
>     dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
>     IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
>     while (reader.Read())
>     {
>         int value = reader.GetInt32(0);
>         string name = reader.GetString(1);
>         int rand = reader.GetInt32(2);
>
>         Debug.Log( "value= "+value+"  name ="+name+"  random ="+  rand);
>     }
>     reader.Close();
>     reader = null;
>     dbcmd.Dispose();
>     dbcmd = null;
>     dbconn.Close();
>     dbconn = null;
> }
> ```
>
> [image] 
>   [image]
>
> Further SQLite Help Visit : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/