# sqlite database does not work on android device

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I have used sqlite in Unity based on instructions from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705925/how-to-connect-a-sqlite-db-in-unity-3d-5no-plugins). It works well in Unity's editor, but when I build an apk file in Unity and install it on my android device it does not recognize my sqlite database.

Actually, the game runs on mobile, but those parts that refer to database do not show. What should I do to make my game connect to the database on a mobile android system?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is for PC, But you can find complete tutorial with a very great example for android device from [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-3d-android-sqlite-examples.114660/).

I test that code and it work perfect.

Comment: slm hosein jan man ino test kardam hanoozam hamoon moshkelo dare age misge emaileto bede man proje testo barat befrestam bebini moshkelesh chie age mishe albate